# How to override Display variable in jmeter.sh

Tags: performance, jmeter

I want to use xvfb to open browser headless for my client-side performance test using jmeter. I am using selenium [Junit sampler] to run the test. How do I override display variable in jmeter so that it does not open browser.?

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

If you're using Firefox you can utilize [FirefoxBinary.setEnvironmentProperty()](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxBinary.html#setEnvironmentProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method

```
FirefoxBinary bin = new FirefoxBinary(new File("/opt/firefox28/firefox"));
bin.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY",":1"); // or where you have Xvbf running
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(bin,new FirefoxProfile());
```

**Option 2**

Consider switching to [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) which is headless by design

**Option 3**

Consider switching to [WebDriver Sampler](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler)'s [HTMLUnitDriver](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HtmlUnitDriverConfig/) support which is also totally headless.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. First option worked for me. Since I am testing it on single page angular app. HtmlUnitDriver is not working very well i.e i am having problems with locators.